# How to send jenkins generated text file to my slack channel

Tags: python, jenkins-pipeline, slack-api, jenkins-cli

I want to a text file to slack which is generated when my Jenkinsfile is run. But I am unable to do that . Please help me

I also tried using slackClient API but since I am not able to use token in Github I was not able to do that.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'pip install jenkinsapi'
                sh 'pip install slackclient'
                sh 'python --version'
            }
        }
        stage('Multilabel Model And storing it into ') {
            steps {
                sh 'python multilabel_model.py'
            }
        }
         stage('Read 2 Report') {
            steps {
                sh 'python read_report.py'
            }
        }
    }
post {
        always {
            echo 'Build Started...!'
           /* archiveArtifacts artifacts: '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins-python-test_master@tmp/gen_output.txt', onlyIfSuccessful: true */
        }
        success {
            echo 'Succeeeded...!'
            slackSend (color: '#00FF00', message: "SUCCESSFUL...! Job ")
            echo "current build12 number: ${currentBuild.number}"
            echo "/home/paras/.jenkins/workspace/test_m/${currentBuild.number}.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried using slack Token . I created a app in slack and gave file:write:user scope and run the below code

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
token  = "xoxp-avcb"
sc = SlackClient(token)

sc.api_call("files.upload", filename=name_file, \
    channels='#jenkin',username='Paras Jain', \
    file1=open(filename12, 'r').read())
files.upload(token,file1)
```

Can some please share some example how to upload file to slack using jenkins .

Comment: You need a Slack token and not a Github token for authentication. Also, Slack has a REST API to do this if you cannot authenticate with a Slack token, at which point you could not use the `slackSend` class though.

Comment: I have used slack token only

Answer (score 1):

You can send a file to slack channel with [Slack Uploader Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-uploader-plugin). But it dos not seem to have pipeline support.

So, you can do it with a curl command, using the [slack API](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) :

```
curl -F file=@jenkins.txt -F channels=yourchannel -H "Authorization: Bearer your token" https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```